# Package was missing for WEEKS, got refunded, then showed up just now....will the company take back the refund?

Tags: refund

As it says in the title.

Will the company be able to electronically take back the refund even without speaking to me?

I'm peed off about the prospect of having to give THEM money for an item that went missing for SEVENTEEN days with NO tracking update, NO useful knowledge from SEVERAL customer service reps with weird names written without capital letters, after TEN days of NO update which smells like a missing item especially during a virus shutdown (maybe the foreign package didn't pass customs, maybe it never even left the airport, what the freak) and no response from the USPS for a week after submitting a report, and NO communication at ALL from the company issuing ANY kind of reassurance nor apology before AND after taking it upon myself to contact THEM. So to basically have to repay them makes me SICK. On top of THAT, folks, they USED MY contact information...to sign me up....for spam websites....I know it was them because it happened right after a live chat, which went badly by the way.

So what BOTHERS and kind of SCARES me is the idea that they can auto-charge me, or take back the refund, because it just sounds like hacking, fraud, theft to dip into my account essentially to do that. Is it even possible for a clothing company or any company to electronically reclaim a refund/recharge me!? Also, including that question, is there ANY responsibility (NOT moral obligation, but legal responsibility) that I could possibly have to actually return a refund for a 17 day late package and horrible customer service? This is their screw up, the package happened to come as a surprise to me and I'm sure to them as well as they said three different and all incorrect delivery dates.

Comment: I also just want to say that the issue is not that I had to wait 17 days. Even though that's unusual, especially for clothes (I shop online many times every month lol). It's that there was no TRACKING for 17 days. Everything normally comes within a week, and tracks everyday while in transit. That's what tracking is. I gave up after 10 days and asked for a refund.

Comment: Hi Amanda, welcome to Personal Finance. Thanks for contributing. The subject of the main question is a good one, but you are covering rather lot of ground (auto-charges, apologies, spam email). Could you perhaps rewrite this to focus on the main question, which I presume is whether you have an obligation to return the refund?

Comment: Also if you want advice about the legal situation you are going to have to tell us what country/state you are in.

Comment: Well your last sentence understands what I want, and everything else is additive detail, so just answering the question would be helpful rather than critiquing my writing style....

Comment: Was this recently? Deliveries are being delayed everywhere, so 2.5 weeks (are you counting work days or all days?) is not too bad really. Was the package coming from outside or within your country?

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple: if you keep the package *and* the refund, it is legally *theft*.

After getting a refund, the package is no longer yours, and you are required to notify them that their package arrived, put *reasonable effort* into keeping it save (like not leave it on the street), and allow them to get it back (on their cost).

Your annoyance about their behavior is understandable, but it doesn't entitle you to keep the package in addition to the refund.

Realistically, if it's not very valuable, and you inform them that it appeared now, they will probably tell you to just keep it (and then it's legal to keep both). They can only request the refund back, if you insist on keeping the package.
In other words: you can't have your cake and eat it.

Comment: I don't think its that simple as calling it "theft". For example the package may count as "unsolicited goods". However in general yes, telling the company the package has arrived is probably the way to go.

Comment: If you intentionally keep something that is not yours, it is theft. You got your money back, so the package is not yours. 'Unsolicited good' won't work here because there is a history that you cannot ignore - at a time it was 'solicited'.

Comment: Actually that's my point. There are circumstances where it is perfectly legal to keep something that is not yours, and "unsolicited goods" is often one of those cases. In some jurisdictions if someone sends you something you didn't ask for you are under to obligation to pay for it or return it (depending somewhat on the circumstances). I'm not so sure that wouldn't apply here. It may be that under these circumstances there is an obligation to return, but it certainly isn't as simple as "it's not yours so it must be theft".

Comment: @DJClayworth I think you meant to put a "no" or "not" in you last comment. Anyway, the OP's case is not unsolicited goods- she solicited (online ordered) them.

Comment: Umm...it's not theft. The refund came a week before the package. It's theft if it comes and I still ask for a refund if tracking incidentally didn't update. Here, tracking didn't update for weeks and they had no idea where the package was, so of course I fought for a refund, and received it. To my surprise, it shows up a week later without the company telling me it's coming. We both gave up. I'm not asking whether I return it. I'm asking CAN THEY AUTOMATICALLY CLAIM A REFUND FROM MY ACCOUNT even WITHOUT COMMUNICATING WITH ME FIRST TO REORDER. I don't want to wake up to money missing.

Comment: @AmandaS. , and the answer says "THEY CAN ONLY REQUEST THE REFUND BACK, IF YOU INSIST ON KEEPING THE PACKAGE". Did you read that far? Is there a word you don't understand? And it would be nice if you stop shouting at volunteers trying to help you for free.

Comment: As said to someone else in the same situation: 


"I doubt its worth the company's time to try to get anything from you forcibly(through legal means or otherwise) after they messed up as described here.

That being said, you did end up with items you 're not entitled to by their mistake. I still think the honorable thing to do would be to contact them to let them know as a gesture of good will and work an outcome that satisfies you both."

Comment: ..Aganju..it's not shouting, it's emphasizing if people don't want to read the text. Caps lock gets their eyes to the main bit that someone wants them to see...and the comments have divulged into a war of wits about irrelevant stuff and strayed a bit from what my question is....yes I'm testy, money is involved and annoying scammer customer service reps. Oh and insulting my intelligence is nasty, immature and unnecessary.

Comment: I know they can REQUEST  a refund BACK. I'm asking, HOW WILL THEY GET THE REFUND BACK....did *you* read that far...? And if I keep the package, what measures can they go to, to get the refund most commonly?